# Data not updated on using eventbus

Tags: events, vue.js, routes

I have eventbus that is fired when a button is clicked, the challenge is that the code inside the callback is not working but the console logging inside same callback works.

This is how I'm firing the event.

```
editCampaign (campaign) {
            eventBus.$emit('editCampaign', campaign);
            this.$router.push('/campaign/create');

        }
```

And below is how I'm listening to the event.

```
created() {
        this.getDetails();
        eventBus.$on('deleted-message', (messages) => {
            this.messageDeleted(messages)
        });

        let self = this;
        eventBus.$on('editCampaign', function(campaign) {
            console.log('campaign edited');
            self.edit = true;
            self.campaign = campaign
        })
    }
```

It console logged `campaign edited` but the `edit` and `campaign` were not updated.

```
data() {
        return {
            campaign: '',
            edit: false
        }
    },
```

Comment: Show the `data`.

Comment: @acdcjunior I have edited it.

Comment: That should work. The only possible problem is the place where that `created()` is at, making the `this` be something else than what it should be.

Comment: This may have to do with the `this` context. Try changing `function (campaign) { /*... */ }` to `(campaign) => { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: @kevguy I  have tried that too, but did not work.

Comment: Is there another alternative I could use aside from the one that I have already used?